# TFS 2015 upgrade stuck

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We are upgrading to TFS 2015 and it seem like almost 8 day the system is still trying to upgrade.  It is stuck on job step[image]

I'm not sure if I should reboot because one of the article http://nokitel.im/index.php/2015/03/24/tfs-2013-upgrade-project-collection-stuck-offline-servicing-state/ said rebooting would make the process start all over.  Any suggestions?
spwho2 shows 
[image]

Answer (score 3):

8 days is definitely too long. As you can see from the log, upgrade job is waiting for fulltext index population and reports status every minute. If the last entry is from July 2nd, then most likely upgrade job has failed. 
You should verify that tfsjobagent service is running on your server first.
If it is not running, you should definitely start it.

If is running, you should query vw_ServicingJobDetail view in the Tfs_Configuration database to find IDs of upgrade jobs.
You can use the following query to see 100 latest step details for a servicing job:

SELECT TOP 100 *

FROM vw_ServicingStepDetail

WHERE JobId = 'your-job-id'

ORDER BY DetailId DESC

Are all 3 upgrade jobs stuck on the same step?

Comment: Only 2 of the 3 jobs are stuck. How would we go about aborting the upgrade jobs? Or what is the next course of action?

Answer (score 3):

During upgrade, there is a servicing step that checks the status of SQL full-text index population. It waits until all work item long text field values are indexes or the crawl is idle. However, the logic doesn't handle the special status code (the status code 6) returned by SQL, and thus keep checking status in a loop.

TFS team is working on getting the problem fixed. However, there isn't a good workaround at this point except trying to identify the problem in SQL full-text index population, and resolve that (so it no longer returns 6 as its status).

As a starting point, check crawl logs inSQL logs folder, and see the exact error being logged there. Also, try pausing/resuming full-text index on WorkItemLongTexts_Dataspace table, and see if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If your database are large then this process can take many days. I know of one instance that took over 5 days to upgrade.

If you mean that it is actually in it's 8th day of upgrade then I would suggest that you raise a support call with MSFT.

Answer (score 0):

Full Text Daemon Search service needs to be turned on.